# How do I convert the result from the lambda expression to a string in Razor c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

First of all, please forgive my ignorance, I am completely new to C# and the MVC format.

I am attempting to pass the resulting value from an item in my model into a custom function. I want to pass a string so I can manipulate it and then pass a string back to the View so I can update my CSS code. The basic form is:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    string tabval = "";
    string status = "";

    //This is where I am getting confused, how do I pass the value of 
    modelItem => item.status to my function StatusType()?

    tabval = StatusType(status);

    <td class="@tabval.ToString()">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)
    </td>
 }
```

Thank you for any help or guidance that you can give. If there is a better way to handle this type of action, I'd be happy to hear those suggestions as well.

Comment: just item.status should do the trick. StatusType(item.status) be sure StatusType is access able by the view as Helper method etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
tabval = StatusType(status);
```

with

```
tabval = StatusType(item.status);
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe it was that simple.